# how to pass more than 9 parameters in nginx

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, regex

this rule

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6&param7=$7&param8=$8&param9=$9&param10=$10 last;
}
```

at `$10` it functions as `$1"0"` so it gives me whatever `$1` value has with a `0` at the end of it

how do i pass more than 9 parameters correctly or if not pssobile to pass more than 9 to do something like

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+) /index.php?param1=$1
    location ^/.+ {
        rewrite ^/.+/(.+) /index.php?param2=$1
            to $3 -> $4 -> $5 -> $6 -> $7 -> $8 -> $9 -> $10
    }
}
```

Comment: Use named captures

Comment: I hope you only ask this for educational purposes... I would NOT want to see that in production!

Comment: @Tommiie yes just educational because this would be a pretty bad structure that tells the backend is super bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(?.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(?<param10>.+)$ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6&param7=$7&param8=$8&param9=$9&param10=$param10 last;
```

}

The `?<argname>` notation tells nginx to capture the regular expression into `$argname` variable. For consistency, you can use the same notation for all variables. I replaced only argument 10 so that the example is shorter.